# Convolutional Neural Networks with Caffe and NEGATIVE or FALSE IMAGES

Tags: neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

When training a set of classes (let's say #clases (number of classes) = N) on Caffe Deep Learning (or any CNN framework) and I make a query to the caffemodel, I get a % of probability of that image could be OK.

So, let's take a picture of a similar Class 1, and I get the result:

> 1.- 96%
>
> 2.- 4%

rest... 0%
the problem is: when I take a random picture (for example of my environment), I keep getting the same result, where one of the class is predominant (>90% probability) but it doesn't belong to any class.

So what I'd like to hear is opinions/answers from people which has experienced this and would have solved how to deal with no-sense inputs to the Neural Network.

My purposes are:

- Train one more extra class with negative images (like with train_cascade).
- Train one more class extra with all the positive images in the TRAIN set, and the negative on the VAL set. But my purposes don't have any scientific base to execute them, that's why I ask you this question.

What would you do?

Thank you very much in advance.

Rafael.

---

**EDIT:**

After two months, A colleague of mine throw me a clue: **The Activation Function.**

I've seen that I use **ReLU** in every layer which means that the value for x is x when x > 0 and 0 otherwise. These are my layers:

```
layers {
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu1"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layers {
  name: "pool1"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "norm1"
  type: LRN
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv2"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "conv2"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu2"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layers {
  name: "pool2"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "norm2"
  type: LRN
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv3"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "conv3"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu3"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layers {
  name: "conv4"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu4"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layers {
  name: "conv5"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu5"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layers {
  name: "pool5"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc6"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu6"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layers {
  name: "drop6"
  type: DROPOUT
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc7"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu7"
  type: RELU
  relu_param {
    negative_slope: -1
  }
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layers {
  name: "drop7"
  type: DROPOUT
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc8"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1000
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "loss"
  type: SOFTMAX_LOSS
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
}
```

if I make ReLU as x for any x (so negative for x < 0) my network converges in accuracy = 0...

Is there better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Train an extra class with negative examples.
Or - this will probably work - use pre-trained network and weights if the network definition satisfies you, for example from ImageNet, and add you classes as additional labels. In that way you have higher chances not to overfit to that additional (the negative) class.  If your network is different you can train it from scratch on a larger dataset instead of using the pre-trained weights.

Comment: Thank you @rursw1 for your answer. Actually training an extra class with negative examples made unstable our network, since it was getting the same results for every image we were sending, so it was an awful solution. Regarding to the second answer, it's a good approach, but we were thinking about lowering the percentage of the results in order to say "this could be probably a #Set2, but with 20%"... are there any other ways which theoretically could work ?? Thank you again.

Comment: @RafaelRuiz : If the first approach made your network unstable, it might point on a problem with your dataset (too small or too specific). Is it the case maybe?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is (too specific)

Answer (score 0):

well i am also working on a similar problem , what i dont understand is even if you are to tell the neural network that this is a +ve image or -ve image , i dont understand how thats going to alter the cascade .I think you have to pick out features from the training image .May be you  can build a hybrid system where it alters the XML cascade